# SQL Group By Issue with same item ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to track the total number of sales a rep has along with the amount of time he was clocked into work.

I have the following two tables:

table1:

```
employeeID | item  |  price  |  timeID  
----------------------------------------
1          |   1   |   12.92 |   123     
1          |   2   |   10.00 |   123     
1          |   2   |   10.00 |   456
```

table2:

```
ID  |  minutes_in_shift
--------------------------
123     |   45
456     |   15
```

I would join these two queries with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  t1.employeeID, t1.item, t1.price, t1.shiftID, t2.minutes_in_shift
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table 2 t2 ON (t2.ID = t1.timeID)
```

Which would return the following table:

```
employeeID | item  |  price  |  timeID  |   minutes_in_shift
---------------------------------------------------
1          |   1   |   12.92 |   123    |   45  
1          |   2   |   10.00 |   123    |   45
1          |   2   |   10.00 |   456    |   15
```

I would like for the consolidate results, however, to have this outcome:

```
employeeID  |   itemsSold   |  priceTotals   |    totaltimeworked
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1         |      3        |    32.92       |       60
```

I could use COUNT and SUM for the items and price but I cannot figure out how to properly show the total time worked in the manner it appears above.
Note: I am only having trouble with calculating the time worked. In shift 123 - employee 1 was working 45 minutes, regardless of how many items he sold.

Any suggestions?

Comment: for the itemsSold and priceTotals use `select employeeID, count(*), sum(price) group by employeeID`. How do you calculate totaltimeworked?

Comment: cha - the items table is one, it is joined to a time worked table which shows the amount of time in store. It is literal time (123 shift he was on 45 minutes, shift 456, he waas on 15 minutes regardless of the items sold)

Comment: It is doable from your sample. However, if you could show us the source SQL that was used to construct your sample we can probably optimise it to get the desired result straight away

Comment: @cha - redesigned question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use the sample data as they are you will need to extract the shifts and sum the minutes, like this:

```
with a as (
  select employeeID, count(*) itemsSold, sum(price) priceTotals  
  from Sampletable1 
  group by employeeID),
b as (
  select employeeID, shiftID, max(minutes_in_shift) minutes_in_shift
  from Sampletable1
  group by employeeID, shiftID),
c as (
  select employeeID, sum(minutes_in_shift) totaltimeworked
  from b
  group by employeeID)
select a.employeeID, a.itemsSold, a.priceTotals, c.totaltimeworked
from a inner join c on a.employeeID = c.employeeID
```

However, with your existing tables the select statement will be much easier:

```
with a as (
  select employeeID, timeID, count(*) itemsSold, sum(price) priceTotals  
  from table1 
  group by employeeID, timeID)
select a.employeeID, sum(a.itemsSold), sum(a.priceTotals), sum(table2.minutes_in_shift) totaltimeworked
from a inner join table2 on a.timeID = table2.ID
group by a.employeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should do what you want:

```sql
SELECT t1.employeeID,
       count(t1.item)                    AS itemsSold,
       sum(t1.price)                     AS priceTotals,
       sum(DISTINCT t2.minutes_in_shift) AS totaltimeworked
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.ID = t1.timeID)
 GROUP BY t1.employeeID;
```

<kbd>[Check on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08196/1)</kbd>

Comment: This may actually be a faster and accurate query as the minutes would never change with the same shiftID. Thanks @vyegorov

Comment: Please use this query with caution. If you have different shifts with the same amount of minutes the query will count them as one and produce wrong result